# "categorisation engine"?

Tags: search-engine, code-search-engine, search-engine-bots

Can any one explain "Categorization Engine" in search engine domain?
I have googled it, but could not find any satisfactory explanations.Even reference links would help!

#### P.S. : Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier if you could provide more context, but generally I think you are referring to the domain of Natural Language Processing known as Categorization or Text Categorization.

That discipline is about parsing natural language text (e.g. English or whatever) and assigning that text to one or more categories.  Was the speaker taking about cars, new medical products, the latest fashion trends, etc.

Some references:

Classification of entire documents:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_classification

Search for concepts in documents:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concept_Mining

Automatic text categorization:

http://nlp.hivefire.com/articles/11632/fully-automatic-text-categorization-by-exploiting-/

Commercial categorization engine:

http://www.sightup.com/en/produits_sightis.html

If you want to use a search engine to find further references, I would suggest searching on *"natural language processing" categorization*